# Pyspark row object flat map

Tags: python, pyspark

I am currently using Pyspark to iterate over a Row object array to access the individual attributes within that Row object. I have written a flat map to try and do this, however I am getting `'action' is not in list` when trying to access action, or any other attribute. The result of `source_data_rdd.take(1)` is listed below.

```
[Row(First Name=Row(action='update', old='john', employee='johnny@example.com', source='manual', timestamp='2020-05-11T16:53:52-04:00', requester='admin@example.com', new='johnny')]
```

For the sake of simplicity, I just included one row in this array.

```
data_rdd = source_data_rdd.flatMap(
    lambda row: (
        (
            getattr(row, row.action)
        )    
    )
)
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried `getattr(row, row['action'])`, `getattr(row, row('action'))`, `getattr(row, row.action`), and many other variations of that but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using lambda it will return Row(FirstName=Row(action=....))
So here x refers to Row(FirstName=someValue)
First access the FirstName and then try to access the attribute which you are looking for.

```
>>> df1.rdd.map( lambda x: x  ).collect()
[Row(First_Name=Row(action='update', employee='johnny@example.com', new='johnny', old='john', requester='admin@example.com', source='manual', timestamp='2020-05-11T16:53:52-04:00'))]
>>> df1.rdd.map( lambda x: x.First_Name.action  ).collect()
['update']
```